# 404 - File or directory not found - with correct URL

Tags: http-status-code-404

i put a file name 'abc.apk' inside the "apk" 's folder and it shows

```
"404 - File or directory not found"
```

when i try to access it with my browser(tried on chrome, FF, and IE). I even try with jdownloader, and it keeps saying that the file is not found...

but it able to shows the picture if i put the picture file inside the "apk" folder. how can i solve this? i wanted the browser auto download the file after i key in the complete url.

i tried some solution from google but none of them works, they asked me to check for the url, move up 1 directory to check the available of the dir.. etc

Comment: Check if extension apk is served by the server. Put .jpg in this folder and get it - if it's found and .apk is not, you need to register .apk with the server. Or disguise it under any registered extension.

Comment: how can i do this? i using a hosting server my and the tool is Parallels Plesk Panel..

Comment: When I wanted to host Silverlight's .xbap file and found it not served by my server, I uploaded it renamed to .jpg, and it worked. But if you have control over server, look how to configure it properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using hosting webserver, send a ticket to your hosting company and ask them to add the file extension into MIME, problem solved.